# Issue while parsing the string to date by DateFormat.getDateInstance using different style and locale

Tags: java, date

I have a use case to parse string to Date for different styles(short, Medium or Full) and locale(US,UK..). so I have used  DateFormat.getDateInstance(style,locale) to parse the string to date, while parsing it is throwing Unparseable exception for "2015/08/14@10:00:00:GMT" except **DateFormat.MEDIUM** style.i want to how to parse the same string to date for **DateFormat.SHORT** or **DateFormat.FULL** style.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,Locale.US);
        Date sd = formatter.parse("2015/08/14@10:00:00:GMT");

    }

}
```

In above code if i modify **DateFormat.MEDIUM** to **DateFormat.SHORT** or **DateFormat.FULL**, it is not parsing the string to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each DateFormat default value (DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.FULL) assumes some string representation, and string represeting DateFormat.MEDIUM is different from what represents DateFormat.SHORT or DateFormat.FULL..

Following tutorial should help you :
[DateFormat Default Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

In your code the date-pattern of `formatter` differs from your date (string representation)

The pattern of `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,Locale.US)` is `MMM d, yyyy` and a correct conversion in code:

```
    //pattern = MMM d, yyyy
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,Locale.US);           
    Date sd_correct = formatter.parse("Aug 14, 2015");
```

To parse your date successfully,  the correct `DateFormat` instance is needed:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd'@'HH:mm:ss:z");
    Date sd = dateFormat.parse("2015/08/14@10:00:00:GMT");
```

See [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745) for more details.